# How should I assign some values from a txt file to an array in Java?

Tags: java

I just started to learn Java. As the title says... I would like to know how should I assign some values from a txt files to an array in Java to work with them (for example to sort them).

For example in C++:

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int v[10];
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("num.txt");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        fin>>v[i];
}
```

**Right guys. Thank you for all the information. I see that is a little bit more complicated than C++, but I'll learn this. Furthermore, when I was intern at a small company I saw that the employees there made a code which scanns an XML files. I guess it's much more complicated, but that's fine. :)**

Comment: Checkout the documentation for `Scanner`, or take a look at this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html

Comment: Just as you learned C++, learn Java. (Books, tutorials, [etc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/).) To solve this task - it's not a problem, nor does it show an attempt - involves understanding several concepts which is why I voted for "Too Broad".

Comment: Is it assumed that each int has it's own line ?

Answer (score 2):

If each line of the file is an integer then:

```
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try
    {
        File myFile = new File("./num.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
        while (scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            results.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // Error handling
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read%20text%20file%20java

**I believe this might help you find a solution.**

---

Alright, getting that *trolling* out of the way.

**PSEUDO CODE:**

```
while not end of file
     get next line
     put next line in a Array List
```

Remember each line is a `String` you can parse strings with `.split()` to get all the words from the file or use some REGEX magic.

**EDIT:**

Ok I saw the other anwser and `scanner.nextInt()` makes me cringe. I had to show an actual code implementation. Using a REGEX to denot the pattern, is a farm more superior method. You can be reading garbage data for all you know! Even if REGEX is beyond you at the moment they are so freaking useful it's important to learn the correct method to do something.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.matches("[\\s\\d]+"){
        String[] temp = line.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
             list.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: next line input might need parsing :p ... Edit: beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will read each character in the file to an ArrayList. In this example white spaces are loaded into the ArrayList, so if this is not intended you have to work some aditional logic :)

If the intention is to fill the array with words instead of characters, make a StringBuilder and inside the loop replace the logic with `sb.append(new String(buffer));`
Then, as progenhard suggested, use the split() method on the returning String from StringBuilder;

```
public class ReadFile {

 public static void main(String[] args){

     FileInputStream is = null;

     try{

         File file = new File("src/example/text");

         is = new FileInputStream(file);

         byte[] buffer = new byte[10];

         List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

         while(is.read(buffer) >=0){

             for(int i=0;i < buffer.length;i++)
                 charArray.add((char)buffer[i]);
             //Used remove the assigned values on buffer for the next iteration
             Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
         }

         for(char character : charArray){
             System.out.println(character);
         }

     }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("Something wrong with the file: " + e);
     }finally{
         if(is != null){
             try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Something wrong when closing the stream: " + e);
            }
         }
     }

}
}
```